# Separate frontend and backend in Java - Spring MVC Framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I'm new at Spring MVC framework i want to learn how to fully separate frontend(html,js etc.) and backend(java).

I'm going to use RESTfull services, play with JSONs.
I think i'm going to build Single Page Application.

Most of tutorials shown in jsp pages which i dont like.

I saw my friends company project(Using Spring MVC) they used Embedded Jetty server and in server configuration they assigned two different paths for frontend and backend paths.

I saw frontend codes there was only html javascripts etc. on the backend side the approach was the same.(Fully Separated !!!)

My question is:'How they pass requests from frontend to backend and get results from backend and update frontend'.

Also they were using Maven backend and frontend defined as modules in the root.

Could you share tutorials so i can understand playing with codes ?

Comment: Your front-end must reside on the client-side. This means the front-end use ajax requests to speak with the back-end.

Comment: Could you be more specific? You mean backend and frontend has to be in same root at maven project? In that project which i mentioned above they set different paths.

Comment: I'm talking about architecture, not your project layout. If you're going to do REST services, you have two way of doing it. Either you make a complete website (front-end) and expose its back-end through REST services. This is for a cheap scenario where you need to interact with other systems, but you don't want them to mess with your db. Or either you make a whole back-end as REST services and you expose an html and javascript website (front-end) which interacts with your back-end through AJAX requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'How they pass requests from frontend to backend and get results from
>   backend and update frontend'

They probably use HTTP[S] as the transport and JSON as the data representation format. Browsers support [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) which allows you to make HTTP connections without reloading the page.

> Could you share tutorials so i can understand playing with codes ?

No, that's not what this site is for.

Comments:

JSP is still very useful for generating HTML on the server. This is pretty close to necessary if you want Google to crawl your site.

Check out Spring Data REST for a framework for quick REST APIs.

Also check out ExtJS or Dojo for good Single Page App frameworks.